# Solr Spellcheck issue for right words searched

Tags: solr, plone

I have implemented Solr 1.4 for spellcheck suggestions but I am facing issue when I have searched the right word even than Solr is suggesting the other words. The example for the same is :

I search "medicine" than it show me the suggestion "medicines" which I don't want as I already type the right word.

One more example I searched for "cimbalta medicine" in this the first word "cimbalta" is misispelled and 2nd word "medicine" is rightly spelled but I get the following Suggesion
**Did you Mean : Cymbalta medicines**  . medicine is changed even when the spelling is correct.

Please suggest me the solution for this.

Thanks In advance

Regards
Abhishek Dixit

Comment: How did you implement the spellchecking? Did you use an external dictionary, or did you build it from one of your fields? If so, is medicine a word that appears in your index? Does medicines occur more frequently?

Comment: We have a dictonary(a text file) in this we have all the words, we have added this dictonary in the solr configuration. Even if the word is right it always suggests the word. If you type medicine, it always suggest medicines.

Comment: I am having the same problem, any answers or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I came across one post that someone said file based spellcheck is currently suggesting even word is in dictionary, you will have to convert the dictionary to solr index to become indexbased spelling.